# how to stop form action url in jquery

Tags: ajax

How to stop form action url of jsp using jquery and invoke url of ajax method.The form is in popupwindow of css code.How to fetch list values of jsonarray object to ajax response

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand exactly what you would like to do.
If you want to stop form submit and use `AJAX` instead, you can just:

```
    $("#your-form-id").submit(function(event) {
            /* stop form from submitting normally */
            event.preventDefault();

            /* JSON object */
            var data = { "field1" : $('#your-form-field1').val(), "field2" : $('#your-form-field2').val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'yourpage.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'JSON', /* result data-type */
                success: function(result){
                 // code if succeeded
                }
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                 // code if failed      
                }
            });             
    });
```

Then you will get a `JSON`, that you can read with something like this (in this example I am creating a list with `<ul>` & `<li>` `HTML` tags):

```
    $('body').append('<ul>');
    $.each(result, function(index, element) {
        $('body').append($('<li>', {
            text: element.fiel1 + " " element.field2
        }));
    });
    $('body').append('</ul>');
```

I hope this helped you a bit :)